# Ошибка при запуске Electron

Tags: python, linux, node.js, npm, electron

Пробую совместить Python с Electron. Но постоянно вылезает такая ошибка:

```
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path /home/dgdays/electron-python
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command sh -c electron .

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/dgdays/.npm/_logs/2020-12-29T17_09_35_105Z-debug.log
```

При этом, если я возьму программу, написанную моим другом, и сделаю `npm start`, то всё спокойно запутится.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, что с этим делать?

PS Вот [ссылка на туториал, по которому делаю](https://www.techiediaries.com/python-electron-tutorial/).

Вот полный код ошибки из логов:

```
0 verbose cli [ '/usr/bin/node', '/usr/bin/npm', 'start' ]
1 info using npm@7.3.0
2 info using node@v12.19.0
3 timing config:load:defaults Completed in 1ms
4 timing config:load:file:/usr/share/nodejs/npm/npmrc Completed in 2ms
5 timing config:load:builtin Completed in 2ms
6 timing config:load:cli Completed in 1ms
7 timing config:load:env Completed in 0ms
8 timing config:load:file:/home/dgdays/electron-python/.npmrc Completed in 1ms
9 timing config:load:project Completed in 2ms
10 timing config:load:file:/home/dgdays/.npmrc Completed in 0ms
11 timing config:load:user Completed in 0ms
12 timing config:load:file:/etc/npmrc Completed in 0ms
13 timing config:load:global Completed in 0ms
14 timing config:load:cafile Completed in 0ms
15 timing config:load:validate Completed in 0ms
16 timing config:load:setUserAgent Completed in 1ms
17 timing config:load:setEnvs Completed in 1ms
18 timing config:load Completed in 8ms
19 verbose npm-session f3d337b65f0eb897
20 timing npm:load Completed in 16ms
21 timing command:run-script Completed in 116ms
22 timing command:start Completed in 118ms
23 verbose stack Error: command failed
23 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/usr/share/nodejs/@npmcli/promise-spawn/index.js:64:27)
23 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:314:20)
23 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1021:16)
23 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:286:5)
24 verbose pkgid electron-python@1.0.0
25 verbose cwd /home/dgdays/electron-python
26 verbose Linux 5.9.0-kali5-amd64
27 verbose argv "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/bin/npm" "start"
28 verbose node v12.19.0
29 verbose npm  v7.3.0
30 error code 1
31 error path /home/dgdays/electron-python
32 error command failed
33 error command sh -c electron .
34 verbose exit 1
```

Comment: Может npm install сначала

Comment: @AzizUmarov, это делал. Делал и в папке и вне папки и даже копировал все модули из РАБОЧЕГО проекта друга. Толку ноль

Comment: @nörbörnën, но проект друга спокойно запускается... А `electron` я устанавливал и локально, и глобально - толку ноль. Именно мои проекту не пашут, но всё что я качаю в инете - замечательно работает((((

Comment: npm -v? python -v? установлен node-gyp? visual studio build tools?

Comment: @nörbörnën, node-gyp не установлен, вроде. visual studio build tools дума ютоже не стоит(на линуксе сижу). npm: 7.3.0, python3: 3.9.1

Comment: я повторил этот кейс на чистом серверном ubuntu. попробуй в папке проекта запустить electron вручную: `./node_modules/.bin/electron .`. у меня ругается так `error while loading shared libraries: libnss3.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`. в моём эксперименте электрону не хватает библиотек. значит нужно выполнить инструкции отсюда https://www.electronjs.org/docs/development/build-instructions-linux#prerequisites

Comment: @nörbörnën, спасибо) Через вашу команду всё запустилось(мистика прям какая-то)

Comment: странно, то, что у тебя не запускается через npm start. давай так: 1) поставь библиотеки (в интсрукции install the following libraries) и попробуй запустить `npm start` 2) если не получится первый пункт установи `npm i --save-dev electron-rebuild`, запусти `./node_modules/.bin/electron-rebuild` и снова `npm start`. надо добить кейс с пускачом и написать ответ, он будет полезным

Comment: @nörbörnën, получилось)

Comment: после первого или после второго предложенного действия?

Comment: После первого))

Comment: Большая часть ошибок начинается с: 23 verbose stack Error: command failed 23 verbose stack at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/usr/share/nodejs/@npmcli/promise-spawn/index.js:64:27) 23 verbose stack at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:314:20) 23 verbose stack at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1021:16) 23 verbose stack at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:286:5) Советую пересмотреть часть кода отвечающую за это

Comment: @0xdb, несовсем понял с чего вы это взяли?

Comment: @0xdb, просто забыл) Я тогда торопился, вот и поставил только галочку)

Comment: @DGDays Ааа, бывает

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Первое: убедитесь, что вы установили пакеты [nodejs](/questions/tagged/nodejs), необходимые для запуска приложения, убедитесь что electron тоже установлен

`$ npm i`

Второе: согласно инструкции [Build Instructions (Linux)](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/development/build-instructions-linux#prerequisites), для запуска на linux приложения, написанного с использованием electron, рекомендуется проверить наличие установленных [nodejs](/questions/tagged/nodejs), [python](/questions/tagged/python) и clang.

Так же должны быть установлены следующие библиотеки (привожу вариант для Ubuntu, в инструкции есть варианты для других распространённых дистрибутивов linux):

```
$ sudo apt-get install build-essential clang libdbus-1-dev libgtk-3-dev \
                       libnotify-dev libgnome-keyring-dev \
                       libasound2-dev libcap-dev libcups2-dev libxtst-dev \
                       libxss1 libnss3-dev gcc-multilib g++-multilib curl \
                       gperf bison python-dbusmock openjdk-8-jre
```

---

Иногда для диагностики ошибок ручной запуск приложения может дать больше информации, чем запуск скриптом `npm start`

```
$ ./node_modules/.bin/electron .
```

Например:

> error while loading shared libraries: libnss3.so: cannot open shared
> object file: No such file or directory

Это гораздо информативнее, чем

```
23 verbose stack Error: command failed
23 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/usr/share/nodejs/@npmcli/promise-spawn/index.js:64:27)
23 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:314:20)
23 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1021:16)
23 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:286:5)
```

---

Иногда может потребоваться явная пересборка electron под конкретное окружение

```
$ npm i --save-dev electron-rebuild
$ ./node_modules/.bin/electron-rebuild

package.json

  "scripts": {
    "rebuild": "electron-rebuild",
    ...
  }
```